# Appropriate way to clear all of the content of a window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am searching for a way to clear the whole content of a window in WPF. So far I couldn't find a way which suits my needs on the net. However I came up with this:

Let's say that I have `MainWindow` view, what I am doing is:

```
MainWindow.Content = null;
MainWindow.Content = new UserControl();
```

It does work but I am unsure whether this approach is safe and correct.

Comment: Why do you want/need to clear the window?

Comment: Well, a specific functionality of the app I am doing requires full layout change of the window, like it is a completely new form/window that has to be maintained within the current/main window. Ps. I am new to WPF/XAML.

Comment: Someone may come up with a better answer, but if you just set `MainWindow.Content` to your new window, the GC will take care of disposing the old window. There's no need to set it to null first.

Comment: Pretty obvious.. Haven't thought about that. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you "clearing content" if you're the one that put it there?

Comment: As I already noted I am new to WPF (started yesterday). What I need is to switch content in the main window. Basically, I have menu where I am using few UserControls to navigate through different options (different groups of buttons). So what I wanted to achieve is to move from the menu to the actual core functionality of the application - removing/clearing the menu and then displaying the new content which is contained in a usercontrol and has nothing to do with the menu, within the same window. So following my logic I had to "clear the content" in some way. I hope that I am clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to set `MainWindow.Content` to `null` first.

All you have to do is:

`MainWindow.Content = new UserControl();`

and the GC will take care of the rest.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: See the comments, the way the OP worded the question wasn't quite what he was trying to do.

Comment: OP wants to know better approach to reset windows Content. This in no way provides better solution for setting Window content. This is always better as a comment. (I did upvote on your comment).

Comment: I confused myself hence my question was not structured properly for which I apologize. I was searching for a behaviour similar to the one where you clean the children of a usercontrol. I didn't take in count that I am clearing static content.